# How to show certain range of hours in each day in Vuetify v-calendar in weekly mode?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In Vuetify [weekly calendar example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/calendars#weekly) every day is displayed as a column that contains full 24 hours. Is it possible to limit this range and show only certain hours per day? Eg. show only hours from 9am to 17pm (typical working hours for each day). This would reduce calendar overall height on the screen and be more clear but I couldn't find the way how to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can by setting the following properties:

```
:first-interval= 9 // The first interval to display in the day view. If intervalMinutes is set to 60 and this is set to 9 the first time in the view is 9am.
:interval-minutes= 60 // The number of minutes the intervals are in the day view. A common interval is 60 minutes so the intervals are an hour.
:interval-count= 8 // The number of intervals to display in the day view.
```